# How to configure SSLInfo programmatically?

Tags: apigee

I am working with Apigee Edge. I'm using named servers so that I can deploy to multiple environments without code changes while accessing different backends.

In a non-prod environment I need to connect to one backend and not use SSL - the server is not setup to accept SSL connections. In a prod environment I need to connect to a different backend and use SSL. In my `TargetEndpoint` I have the following `HTTPTargetConnection`:

```
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <SSLInfo>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled>
    </SSLInfo>
    <LoadBalancer>
        <Server name="myServer"/>
    </LoadBalancer>
    <Path>/my_path</Path>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Is it possible to change `SSInfo/Enabled` programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The load balanced server(target server) connection should handle this. In you non prod environment configure the server to use non-SSL and SSL in prod. The proxy is abstracted out from the server configuration - as long as the target server name remains same the proxy will work.

Please look at the Target server API to change configuration.

http://apigee.com/docs/api/api_resources/51-targetservers

By the way target servers are specific to environments so it should work in you case.

Here is JSON to add SSLInfo:

```
{
    "host": "0.0.0.0",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "name": "my_Server",
    "port": 80,
    "sSLInfo": {
        "ciphers": [ ],
        "clientAuthEnabled": false,
        "enabled": false,
        "ignoreValidationErrors": false,
        "protocols": [ ]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only specify name, host, and port for the target server when you create it. To use SSL with a named server you have to set SSL enabled to true.